# gcc linker option (or other) for sectioning memory and leaving chunks of memory unused

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I was wondering if there are any linker options or otherwise any options to make the linker store a certain amount of compiled code/data into a section of memory for then to leave an area free after that, and then start a new section after that.

The reason I'm asking is for updating code later on, and then updating only some sections of the binary not all. And possibly then having later compilation automatically place unchanged code into the same sections as they already occupy. And the changed code sections being allowed to use the unused memory of the section it occupied last.

I can see that this can probably be done manually with a linker script and then using linker options in the code when coding. But I'm wondering if it is possible to do this automatically.

I would consider such an automatic partitioning non trivial as if a function was moved all references to that function would have to be updated to so that it could quickly become messy.

Comment: This is a drastically harder problem than you're making it out to be... which is why such an automatic option does not exist.

Comment: Yes I realize that this is non trivial. I'm considering to suggest this as a master thesis from the company I work for. We use gcc quite often. But before suggesting it I wanted to check if anybody knew if an implementation already existed. My guess is that it could be done by parsing "old" and new mapfiles and posibly create some output that could be used in order to do partitioning before sending it on to the linker. But I'm not certain it is possible at all. A failure would be a good result to if it explained whell what was done and why it fails.

Comment: What's the end goal? Live update of a running process? If anyone wanted such a thing, I'd imagine they would have done so before trying to hot-patch the running  kernel.

Comment: low update time and power use of bootloader in wire-les battery application

Comment: You should probably be using a linker script when building a bootloader for an embedded system anyway, no? Just change it to leave more space. If you go to use this space in the future you're going to need to know where it is and how big.

Comment: The application software would not be running of the application section/sections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82084/discussion-between-elvishpriestley-and-jonathon-reinhart).